# How to drive cross-hair using scatter plot bubble coordinates

Tags: d3.js

How can I draw a cross hair when I click on bubbles both on x axis and y axis.

I know my `cx` and `cy` values, which are for example:

```
381.5
222.9
```

I am going to use this code to draw a `<line>`,

```
.on("click", function(d,i) {
      svg.append("svg:line")
        .attr("x1", 300).attr("y1", 300)
        .attr("x2", 50).attr("y2", 50)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", 3);
   });
```

What values should i have to give `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` according to my bubble. I can't understand this. And please explain it to me.

Comment: Can you post your full code and explain more about the desired output? When you click on a bubble, you want to draw a crosshair on the intersecting points on the x-axis and y-axis?

Comment: Yes mdml. I want to do that